# Creation of Marquee in .NET windows application

Tags: c#, .net, marquee

I have to create a marquee in a .NET windows application. What is the best to do this with C#?

Comment: I understood the question as a marquee selection, but other people seem to have different ideas. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you go through your other questions and see mark any answers that correctly helped you, as the accepted answer. This will give rep to those who help you and yourself, which encourages other people to help.

Comment: Please clarify: Marquee = scrolling text OR styled progress bar OR something else?

Comment: @bryan:what do u mean.i am not getting what do u want to say exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the simple code on how you can do marquee in C#

```
        private int xPos=0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Width == xPos)
            {
                //repeat marquee
                this.lblMarquee.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 40);
                xPos = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblMarquee.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, 40);
                xPos++;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just place a `ProgressBar` control and change its `Style` to `Marquee` from the designer. You'll see the animation immediately.

If you're referring to text marquee, just place a `Label` control and user the [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to increment the `Location.X` property of the label. When X coordinate is equal to the size of the control, just reset it and start over.

Comment: He could also refer to a _text_ that is scrolling, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int j = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0 + i, 111);
            label3.Visible = true;

        }
        for (int i = j; i-- > 0; )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(15);
            label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0 + i, 111);
            label3.Visible = true;
            if (i < 1)
                button_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```